# How do I align the bottom of two square right triangles?

Tags: inkscape, alignment

I am having this problem at trying to align these two right triangles together at their hypotenuse. I tried all the align commands but I don't know which is the right one to make those sides to be perfectly aligned together.

This is better illustrated below:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

In adition to this question there is also how to align the hypotenuse of this triangle in paralell with respect of the bottom edge on the page on Inkscape. Can someone help me with the steps?. Please I am not that savvy with this program so a detailed step by step guide would help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume there's a good reason why the triangles are not drawn from the start to their wanted positions. In that case you can rotate them manually. Point snapping makes it exact.

At first drag the triangles so that the leftmost bottom corners snap. Drag from the top ruler a horizontal guide to the same point:

[image]

Click with the normal selection tool a triangle to turn it to rotate mode. Drag the rotation center to the common corner. It snaps if you have also snap to rotation center ON.

Rotate the other bottom corner to snap to the guide. Do the same to both triangles.

[image]

If the triangles happen to be otherwise identical, but mirror images of each other you can as well duplicate (=Ctrl+D) that one which has horizontal hypotenuse and flip the duplicate horizontally.